# How to create file association in WPF application with ClickOnce?

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have used ClickOne and Set up Project in VS 2010 but it does not working.
I double click on associate file but it does not open in my WPF Application.

Plz help me resolve this issue, step to step....

Thank so much!

Comment: Understand the file does not load in the WPF Application.  What does happen?

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892924.aspx) on MSDN has a good step-by-step approach.

**EDIT**
If ClickOnce is not working for you, you can try doing the installation with Inno Setup.  It is an outstanding (and free) installation utility.  It is available [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php), and [this link](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#assoc) shows you how to create file associations.

I use Inno Setup for all of my desktop application installations.

Comment: Thanks for helping. If I want to get the path which i double click, how can I do ?

Comment: @Hung Nguyen, I am not sure I understand what path you are talking about.

Comment: i am writing a WPF Application. I want to double click  a custom file such as .myfile and my app will read this file to show it's content. When i use inno setup, how can i get path of file which i double click?

Comment: You don't need to do that.  Once you set the file association, when you double-click the file, it will start your application.