# c# wpf set link in the right-click context menu of windows

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I want to set in the right-click menu of windows, a shortcut to my app.
The goal is to select a document (image, pdf etc.) -> right-click -> 'Send with my app' ( and optionnaly open a certain class with arguments, like the files path)

I've saw some many possibilities to do that ...

but I would like to know **the good way** to do that with a c# wpf app.

The goal is to send an installation program to many clients to allow them to use the app, and set the entry on the context menu

Comment: answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10016323/1979354

Answer (score 3):

In order to show custom options in Windows context menu, you will need to update the registry. Here is how to do it

http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

Once done, in your wpf application, you can get the command line arguments passed using :

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

from these args, you can extract any argument passed (file location etc)