# Get file from Windows Explorer "open with" Context Menu C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, contextmenu, windows-explorer

How i can get the txt file from the Windows Explorer when the user chooses to open a ".txt" file with the wpf application in c# and display the Text from the .txt file in a Textbox?

[image: Here is a image the Context menu that i mean.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# wpf set link in the right-click context menu of windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176448/c-sharp-wpf-set-link-in-the-right-click-context-menu-of-windows)

Comment: Sadly no, I want to get the text from the txt that the user chosen to open with the Wpf application.

Comment: Use the answer from the post above to get the path of the right-clicked text file, then read the contents from the file using [System.IO.File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-5.0) and display the text in your textbox by setting its Text property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write the complete answer here so you can accept it.

The solution is:

1. Get the path of the right-clicked file based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34177839/6248380).
2. Read the contents of the file using [System.IO.File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-5.0)
3. Display the text in the textbox by setting its Text property.

Answer (score 0):

In Code this would be for richtextbox

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();




        try
        {
            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        
            richtextbox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
            richtextbox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(File.ReadAllText(args[1]))));

          
        }
        catch
        {

        }


    }
```

and for nomral textbox

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();




    try
    {
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();


         textbox.Text = File.ReadAllText(File.ReadAllText(args[1]));


    }
    catch
    {

    }


}
```